# erro em comparação usando substring

Tags: java, eclipse

```
maquina += numeroale.nextInt(4);
        maquina += numeroale.nextInt(4);

        //vez da mqauina
    for (int i = 0; i < maquina.length(); i++) {

        System.out.println("valor atual"+maquina.substring(i,1));

        if((maquina.substring(i,1)).equals("0")){
            System.out.println("0 pressed");
            b1.setBackground(Color.white);




            play("b1");




        }
        else if((maquina.substring(i,1)).equals("1")){
            System.out.println("1 pressed");
            b2.setBackground(Color.white);

            play("b2");

        }
        else if((maquina.substring(i,1)).equals("2")){
            System.out.println("2 pressed");
            b3.setBackground(Color.white);


            play("b3");



        } else if((maquina.substring(i,1)).equals("3")){
            System.out.println("3 pressed");
            b4.setBackground(Color.white);


        play("b4");

        }
        else{

        }



    }
```

o código não consegue comparar a segunda posição, mas a primeira vai depois da erro

Comment: De onde vem essa variável `maquina` e o que ela guarda? Adicione um [mcve]. Como já lhe disse na outra pergunta, adicionar um pedaço solto e não reproduzivel, só dificulta que você receba uma resposta.

Comment: só queria saber se a comparação está correta nos if

Comment: a variavel numeroale gera numeros aleatorio random

Comment: Se maquina é integer, porque você está usando substring??

Comment: maquina é uma String

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que [o segundo parametro (`endIndex`) de substring é exclusivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Ele indica também a posição onde deve acabar, e não o número de caracteres como é feito noutras linguagens.

Isto quer dizer que o `endIndex` tem de ser obrigatoriamente maior (pelo menos mais 1) do que o `beginIndex`. Dai o seu código falhar na segunda iteração onde o valor de `i` é igual a 1.

Corrija para o seguinte, em todo o lado:

```
maquina.substring(i, i + 1)
```

Comment: não sabia disso

Comment: obrigado ! deu certo agora